# How do I calculate the boosted decay rate?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, radiation

For example for the beta decay of the neutron, one usually assumes that the neutron is at rest in the initial frame and calculates more easily the decay rate. But what if the neutron is not at rest?

The obvious answer is to recalculate everything from scratch, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The decay time $T$ is measured in the rest frame of the decaying particle. In other words, it is measured in the proper time of the particle. If the decaying particle moves, its decay time undergoes time dilation, so the decay time measured in the system, where it is observed moving with speed $v$, is:

$$T' =\gamma T$$

where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}}$.

So if it moves with $v\cong c$ it only decays after a much dilated time.

But  note, neutrons rarely move a ultrarelativistic speed. So in a realistic scenario the effect would be quite small.